# Javafx change PieChart color

Tags: javafx-2

I have a list of color representing a color sequence. I want to apply the new color sequence to the piechart data.

```
private final int CASPIAN_COLOR_COUNTS = 8;   
public void setPieChartColor(PieChart chart, List<String> colors) {

    chart.getData().get(i);   // for debug to get the node name (.data)

    /**
     * Set Pie color
     */
    int i = 0;
    for (String color : colors) {
        final Node node = chart.lookup(".data" + i);
        node.getStyleClass().remove("default-color" + (i % CASPIAN_COLOR_COUNTS));
        node.getStyleClass().add(color);
        i++;
    }
```

but all chart data take **Only one color from Caspian** color.

Comment: I have list of color which contains the color sequence. i want to apply my new color sequence to piechart data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve custom pie colors in code using a method such as:

```
private void applyCustomColorSequence(
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData, 
    String... pieColors) {
  int i = 0;
  for (PieChart.Data data : pieChartData) {
    data.getNode().setStyle(
      "-fx-pie-color: " + pieColors[i % pieColors.length] + ";"
    );
    i++;
  }
}
```

Note that the method must be applied after the chart has been shown on an active scene (otherwise the `data.getNode()` call will return `null`).

Here is some [sample code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5095145) which uses it.

[image: coloredpiechart]

---

You can accomplish the same effect using [css stylesheets](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm).

For example a css stylesheet containing the following style definitions will change the default colors of a pie chart when the stylesheet is applied against a given chart.

```
.default-color0.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #ffd700; }
.default-color1.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #ffa500; }
.default-color2.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #860061; }
.default-color3.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #adff2f; }
.default-color4.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #ff5700; }
```

For an example of the stylesheet based approach: see the "Setting Colors of a Pie Chart" section of the [Styling Charts with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm) tutorial.

The stylesheet approach has an advantage that the styles are separated from the code.  It has the disadvantage that the colors are must be set the time the stylesheet are created rather than at runtime and the color sequence is restricted to a fixed number of colors (8).

In general, the stylesheet approach is recommended for most applications.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, your code work good but when i add tooltip to pie chart with mouse event and as mouse move over the chart it return back css colors again.

Comment: i found the problem in the mouse event the style was set to empty `node.setStyle("")`,when i comment it all thing go right.

Comment: When using your applyCustomColorSequence() function the colours of the slices do change however the colours in the legend do not get updated meaning they become inconsistent.

Comment: Also I cannot get the css method to work, specifying the css in chart.setStyle() has simply no effect. If you know how to change the colour of the slices and the legend in a consistent way could you please show an example? Thank you.

Comment: You can't apply css selectors using setStyle, you need to use a stylesheet as defined in the reference I provided.  The sample I provided hides the chart legend so that it's colors are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The css styles might not work if your values are negative. This might be a bug but I had to convert my values to positive values for the styles to work. When the values were negative all pies were white in color.