# Constant colors on a PieChart

Tags: java, charts, javafx

I have a JavaFX PieChart, and I want to have a color associated with specific regions.  However, it seems like I can only have colors associated with the order that the `Data` is added to the chart.  For example, if I want to plot the colors of cars in a parking lot, I could do this:

```
.default-color0.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #FF0000; }
.default-color1.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #00FF00; }
.default-color2.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #0000FF; }
.default-color3.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #FFFF00; }
.default-color4.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #00FFFF; }
```

As long as I add my "red car" data first, and then the "green car" data, etc, everything is fine.  But If there are no red cars, and I don't add that Data, then the green cars become red, as they are the first data point.  I could add a `Data("Red", 0)`, but then that shows up in my PieChart as a slice with zero area, but it still has a label, and it could be confusing.  Is there any way to avoid this?  Either to mark `Data` objects with zero data as invisible, or assign constant colors to categories?

Comment: It sounds like it would be better to set those values by code and when adding the Data. So you know that the colour is matching the data.

Comment: Get the node and change it's color. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15236593/2855515

Comment: I did try that, but the legend color remained the same.  I suppose there's probably a way to change that too, but that's kind of annoying.  Seems like probably the best option, though.

Comment: Legend is just a Node, you can make your own and call setLegend(node);

Comment: On what object do I call `setLegend`?  On `PieChart`, there's only `setLegendSide` and `setLegendVisible`.

Comment: [Here's the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/Chart.html#setLegend-javafx.scene.Node-) but it's protected ??.  [Here's another sample from jewelsea](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1422628)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's what I ended up doing (and it works):

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < usedColors.size(); i++) {
      for (Node node : chart.lookupAll(String.format(".default-color%d.chart-pie", i))) {
        node.setStyle(String.format("-fx-pie-color: #%06x;", usedColors.get(i)));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Where `usedColors` is a List containing the correct colors in order.  This will affect the legend as well.  Using runLater is necessary.

And thanks to everyone in the comments for your help.

Comment: Thanks man I wouldn't ever expected that only using Platform.runLater() can fix this issue. I've spent couple of hours at this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution still just has you adding the items in order of the colors.  It's not hard to get a reference to the legend.  There's no way to add a color to the PieChart.Data but you could make your own class.

```
import com.sun.javafx.charts.Legend;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomPie extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        PieData pieData = new PieData();
        pieData.add(new PieChart.Data("Grapefruit", 13d), Color.AQUA);
        pieData.add(new PieChart.Data("Oranges", 25d), Color.ALICEBLUE);
        pieData.add(new PieChart.Data("Plums", 10d), Color.AQUAMARINE);
        pieData.add(new PieChart.Data("Pears", 22d), Color.BLUE);
        pieData.add(new PieChart.Data("Apples", 30d), Color.BLUEVIOLET);

        final MyPie pieChart = new MyPie(pieData.pieChartData);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(pieChart));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        for (PieChart.Data data : pieData.pieChartData) {
            int idx = pieData.pieChartData.indexOf(data);
            Color color = pieData.pieChartColors.get(idx);
            data.getNode().setStyle("-fx-pie-color: " + color.toString().replace("0x", "#") + ";");
            pieChart.legend.getItems().get(idx).setSymbol(new Rectangle(8, 8, color));
        }
    }
}

class MyPie extends PieChart {
    public Legend legend;

    public MyPie(ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData) {
        super(pieChartData);
        legend = (Legend) getLegend();
    }
}

class PieData {
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<Color> pieChartColors = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public void add(PieChart.Data data, Color color){
        pieChartData.add(data);
        pieChartColors.add(color);
    }
}
```

I haven't checked if adding/removing data confuses it but the data structure could be improved.